# While making a dial chart getting Unsupported chart type yet: dial error

Tags: java, jfreechart, zk, zul

I am trying to plot a dial chart using zk framework (JFreeChart). Please find below the code:

**chart1Dial.zul**

```
<?page title="new page title" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"?>
 <zk>
  <window title="new page title" border="normal">

   <hlayout spacing="10px" apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" 
      viewModel="@id('vm') @init('demo.chart.dial.DialChartVM')">
   <chart id="chartC" width="250" height="250" 
    paneColor="#ffffff" type="dial"
    model="@bind(vm.celsiusModel)" engine="@bind(vm.engine)"/>

   <!--     <chart id="chartF" width="250" height="250" 
    paneColor="#ffffff" type="dial" 
    model="@bind(vm.fahrenheitModel)"/> -->
    </hlayout>

    </window>
   </zk>
```

**ChartData.Java**:

```
 package demo.chart.dial;

 import java.awt.Color;

 import org.zkoss.zul.DialModel;
 import org.zkoss.zul.DialModelScale;

 import demo.chart.ChartColors;

public class ChartData {

public static DialModel createCelsiusModel(){
    DialModel model = new DialModel();

    model.setFrameFgColor("#808080");
    model.setFrameBgAlpha(255);
    model.setFrameBgColor("#FFFFFF");
    model.setFrameBgColor1("#000000");
    model.setFrameBgColor2("#000000");

    model.setCapRadius(0.1);

    model.setGradientDirection("vertical");

    return model;
}

public static int toFahrenhit(int celsius){
    return Math.round(celsius * 9 / 5 + 32);
}

public static int toCelsius(int fahrenheit){
    return Math.round((fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9);
}
}
```

**DialChartEngine.Java**

```
   package demo.chart.dial;

  import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
  import org.zkoss.zkex.zul.impl.JFreeChartEngine;
  import org.zkoss.zul.Chart;
  import org.zkoss.zul.DialModel;
  import org.zkoss.zul.DialModelScale;
  import java.awt.Color;

 import demo.chart.ChartColors;

 public class DialChartEngine extends JFreeChartEngine {

 private boolean explode = false;

 public boolean prepareJFreeChart(JFreeChart jfchart, Chart chart) {



    DialModel model = new DialModel();

    DialModelScale scale = model.newScale(-10.0, 60.0, 230, -280, 10.0, 4);


    //scale's configuration data
    scale.setValue(27);
    scale.setText("Celsius");
    scale.newRange(-10,  0, ChartColors.toHtmlColor(Color.getHSBColor(0.55f, 0.8f, 1)), 0.61, 0.603);
    scale.newRange(  0, 10, ChartColors.toHtmlColor(Color.getHSBColor(0.3f , 0.8f, 1)), 0.61, 0.603);
    scale.newRange( 10, 20, ChartColors.toHtmlColor(Color.getHSBColor(0.18f, 0.8f, 1)), 0.61, 0.603);
    scale.newRange( 20, 30, ChartColors.toHtmlColor(Color.getHSBColor(0.12f, 0.8f, 1)), 0.61, 0.603);
    scale.newRange( 30, 40, ChartColors.toHtmlColor(Color.getHSBColor(0.08f, 0.8f, 1)), 0.61, 0.603);
    scale.newRange( 40, 50, ChartColors.toHtmlColor(Color.getHSBColor(0.05f, 0.8f, 1)), 0.61, 0.603);
    scale.newRange( 50, 60, ChartColors.toHtmlColor(Color.getHSBColor(0.0f , 0.8f, 1)), 0.61, 0.603);
    scale.setTickColor("#FFFFFF");
    scale.setNeedleType("pin");
    scale.setNeedleColor("#FF0000");

    return true;

 }

 public void setExplode(boolean explode) {
        this.explode = explode;
    }
  }
```

**DialChartVM.Java**

```
package demo.chart.dial;

import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.BindingParam;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.GlobalCommand;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.Init;
import org.zkoss.zul.DialModel;



public class DialChartVM {

DialModel celsiusModel;

DialChartEngine engine;

public DialModel getCelsiusModel() {
    return celsiusModel;
}

/*public DialModel getFahrenheitModel() {
    return fahrenheitModel;
}*/

 public DialChartEngine getEngine() {
        return engine;
    }

@Init
public void init() {
    int celsius = 27;
    celsiusModel = ChartData.createCelsiusModel();

    engine = new DialChartEngine();
}

}
```

When I am trying to execute the below code I am getting an error message as :

Unsupported chart type yet: dial

Below is the ***error***:

```
org.zkoss.zk.ui.UiException: Unsupported chart type yet: dial
at org.zkoss.zkex.zul.impl.JFreeChartEngine.getChartImpl(JFreeChartEngine.java:242)
at org.zkoss.zkex.zul.impl.JFreeChartEngine.drawChart(JFreeChartEngine.java:266)
at org.zkoss.zul.Chart.doSmartDraw(Chart.java:243)
at org.zkoss.zul.Chart.access$100(Chart.java:82)
at org.zkoss.zul.Chart$SmartDrawListener.onEvent(Chart.java:224)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.onEvent(AbstractComponent.java:2746)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:2717)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:2658)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process(EventProcessor.java:136)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.processEvent(UiEngineImpl.java:1765)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.process(UiEngineImpl.java:1550)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execNewPage0(UiEngineImpl.java:512)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execNewPage(UiEngineImpl.java:356)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.process(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:215)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.doGet(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:136)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please let me know how to proceed further. Thank you

Comment: I think your zkex version is to low to support the DialModel.

Comment: @chillworld I tried with the latest zkex version(3.6.2) as well, however having the same error.

Comment: euuh the latest isn't 3.6.2 : try this one : `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zkex</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.2</version>
        </dependency>`

Comment: I am not using maven so I have to download the jars manually, and I am unablle to find the version 8.0.2

Comment: it's zk EE, so try https://www.zkoss.org/download/freshly/ (zkex is included in the zkee-bin-eval)

Comment: Thank you @chillworld, my code is working now. I have modified a bit as I have downloaded the new jars.

Comment: You can post an [answer to your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188) for others.

Answer (score 0):

I am now able to draw the dialchart as I have downloaded all the zk-jars(version 8)

Please find below my working code:

**chart1Dail.zul**

```
<?page title="new page title" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"?>
<zk>
<window title="new page title" border="normal">

<hlayout spacing="10px" apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" 
viewModel="@id('vm') @init('demo.chart.dial.DialChartVM')">
<chart id="chartC" width="250" height="250" 
    paneColor="#ffffff" type="dial"
    model="@bind(vm.celsiusModel)" />

</hlayout>

</window>
</zk>
```

**DialChartVM.java**

```
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.BindingParam;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.GlobalCommand;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.Init;
import org.zkoss.zul.DialModel;



public class DialChartVM {

DialModel celsiusModel;

public DialModel getCelsiusModel() {
    return celsiusModel;
}


@Init
public void init() {
    int celsius = 50;
    celsiusModel = ChartData.createCelsiusModel(celsius);

}
```

}

**ChartData.Java**

```
import java.awt.Color;

import org.zkoss.zul.DialModel;
import org.zkoss.zul.DialModelScale;

import demo.chart.ChartColors;

public class ChartData {

public static DialModel createCelsiusModel(int value){
    DialModel model = new DialModel();



    DialModelScale scale = model.newScale(-10.0, 60.0, 230, -280, 10.0, 4);


    //scale's configuration data
    scale.setValue(value);
    scale.setText("Celsius");
    scale.newRange(-10,  0, ChartColors.toHtmlColor(Color.getHSBColor(0.55f, 0.8f, 1)), 0.61, 0.603);
    scale.newRange(  0, 10, ChartColors.toHtmlColor(Color.getHSBColor(0.3f , 0.8f, 1)), 0.61, 0.603);
    scale.newRange( 10, 20, ChartColors.toHtmlColor(Color.getHSBColor(0.18f, 0.8f, 1)), 0.61, 0.603);
    scale.newRange( 20, 30, ChartColors.toHtmlColor(Color.getHSBColor(0.12f, 0.8f, 1)), 0.61, 0.603);
    scale.newRange( 30, 40, ChartColors.toHtmlColor(Color.getHSBColor(0.08f, 0.8f, 1)), 0.61, 0.603);
    scale.newRange( 40, 50, ChartColors.toHtmlColor(Color.getHSBColor(0.05f, 0.8f, 1)), 0.61, 0.603);
    scale.newRange( 50, 60, ChartColors.toHtmlColor(Color.getHSBColor(0.0f , 0.8f, 1)), 0.61, 0.603);
    scale.setTickColor("#FFFFFF");
    scale.setNeedleType("pin");
    scale.setNeedleColor("#FF0000");

    model.setFrameFgColor("#808080");
    model.setFrameBgAlpha(255);
    model.setFrameBgColor("#FFFFFF");
    model.setFrameBgColor1("#000000");
    model.setFrameBgColor2("#000000");

    model.setCapRadius(0.1);

    model.setGradientDirection("vertical");

    return model;
}

public static int toFahrenhit(int celsius){
    return Math.round(celsius * 9 / 5 + 32);
}

public static int toCelsius(int fahrenheit){
    return Math.round((fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9);
}
}
```

I have removed the **DialChartEngine.Java** file.